# Computer Graphics and pixmap

Tags: graphics, bitmap, pixel, pixmap

I have a question:

Assuming transfer rate of 0.1mb/sec how much time would be necessary to load pixmaps with resolution of 512x512.

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

512 * 512 = 262144 pixels

Assuming 8 bits per color RGB, 262144 * 3 = 786432 bytes or 0.75 mb

So it would take about 7.5 seconds... ideally.

Throw in an alpha channel and it goes up to 10 seconds.

Note that calculation is for RAW pixmap data. If it is compressed, like JPEG or PNG the file will be smaller, but the end size will depend on the content of the image, so there is no way to tell in advance.

Comment: aspect ratio is 1 given in the questions... Thanku.

Comment: m not getting  how it is.. ?

Comment: means how u get from 0.75mb to  7.5 sec

Comment: 0.75 / 0.1 = 7.5 - e.g. how many steps of 0.1 it will take to make 0.75

Comment: Means frame buffer size/transfer rate ?? am i right?

Comment: This is not even programming question, it is simple math. You should post such questions in http://math.stackexchange.com instead of here on SO. Good luck.